# How to insert some table information to another table column?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am a beginner in mySQL and I am trying to create a user's table with information about the user (see code) and populate a column with details that I get from a new table that gets created.

Now I want to be able to put some information from the 'creditcards' table like number for example, to the 'users' table which includes a column 'creditcard', so that I can see each user's credit card number.

I am also comparing the name of the user with the name of the credit card owner so it populates the table according to the user.

I couldn't find any information about the specific problem I am having here.
Here's how I am trying to write:

```
con.query(createNewCreditCard, [name, type, number, expiration, svss], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          const JoinCreditCard = 'INSERT INTO users (creditcard) SELECT number,name FROM creditcards WHERE users.name = creditcards.name';

const userCreateModel = `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    phonenumber VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    creditcard INT(11),
    salt VARCHAR(255),
    created_at DATE,
    update_at DATE,
    deleted_at DATE,
    lastSignIn DATE,
    PRIMARY key (id)
  )
`;

const CreditCardModel = `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS creditcards (
      id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
      type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      number INT(12) NOT NULL,
      expiration DATE,
      svss INT(3) NOT NULL,
      created_at DATE,
      PRIMARY key (id)
  )
`;
```

I am trying to create a user named ula and then a credit card with the name ula (and all other columns) which I am sending from postman. 
The credit card part in nodejs looks like this:

```
const createCreditCard = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {
      name,
      type, 
      number, 
      expiration,
      svss
    }: {
      name: String,
      type: String,
      number: String,
      expiration: String,
      svss: String
    } = req.body;

    const createAt = new Date(Date.now());

    try {
      const createNewCreditCard = 'INSERT INTO creditcards (name, type, number, expiration, svss) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
      con.query(createNewCreditCard, [name, type, number, expiration, svss], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          const JoinCreditCard = 'UPDATE users SET creditcard=' + number + ' WHERE name="' +  name + '"';
          console.log(results);              
        }
      });

      res.status(201).send({ success: true, message: 'New credit card was created', data: {name, type, number, expiration, svss} });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
    }

    await next;
  }
```

The server returns 201, I go to mysql, open users, see column creditcard and its `NULL`.

Comment: When you do this kind of relashionship between tables, it's usually better that the creditcard in `users` only stores the `id` from the `creditcards` table. Like this, relations are on the primary key and it's more optimized. With the same idea, it would be useless to store the `name` in the `creditcards` which you have already in the users table. To make it short: use primary ids for relations and avoid duplicate the data across tables

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that too but it was just an example with the `number`. I am using the `name` as a comparison so that the appropriate creditcard goes to the appropriate user.

Comment: But I still don't know how can I make the code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the entry already exists in the database for `users` table, you should use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

An example that should work with your code (you already know `name` and `number` as vars because you just created the credit card info with them, no need to select them again):

```
con.query(createNewCreditCard, [name, type, number, expiration, svss], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          const JoinCreditCard = 'UPDATE users SET creditcard=' + number + ' WHERE name="' +  name + '"';
```

**EDIT**: this is the new code from your edit. You already use prepared statements, so forget my notice about that. I've updated the query to follow this. What was missing in your code is that you need to actually do the query! Only declaring the constant won't do anything to your database..

```
    try {
      const createNewCreditCard = 'INSERT INTO creditcards (name, type, number, expiration, svss) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
      con.query(createNewCreditCard, [name, type, number, expiration, svss], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log(results);
          const JoinCreditCard = 'UPDATE users SET creditcard=? WHERE name=?';
          con.query(JoinCreditCard, [number, name], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
            } else {
              console.log(results);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      res.status(201).send({ success: true, message: 'New credit card was created', data: {name, type, number, expiration, svss} });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
    }
```

**NOTE**: you should know that using the name to reference the credit card will not allow you to have multiple credit cards for one user, and should be careful about users with the same name, or else this query will update both users. It would be safer to always use the user `id` field in the `WHERE` clause. (you should know it at this point)

**THIS IS WHAT I RECOMMEND:**

- it's usually better that the creditcard in `users` only stores the id from the creditcards table. Like this, relations are on the primary key and it's more optimized (you need to get the id after the credit card creation request, in an inner `SELECT` in following code).
- use the ids to identify rows updates, to prevent 2 users to be updated
- delete `name` from creditcards table, it's already in users
- having a third table to reference the relations like states user1974729 is not mandatory, however, it will be the case if you conveniently want to be able to have more than one credit card per user or more than one user that share a card (1 to n relation)

code:

```
//relation based on id instead of number stored in users + name removed. I assume at this point, you know the id of your user (in var "id" used below in `WHERE` clause)
con.query(createNewCreditCard, [type, number, expiration, svss], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          const JoinCreditCard = 'UPDATE users SET creditcard=(SELECT id FROM creditcards WHERE type="' + type + '" AND number="' + number + '" AND expiration="' + expiration + '" AND svss="' + svss + '") WHERE id="' + id + '"';

//no change in userCreateModel

//deleted "name" in CreditCardModel
const CreditCardModel = `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS creditcards (
      id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      number INT(12) NOT NULL,
      expiration DATE,
      svss INT(3) NOT NULL,
      created_at DATE,
      PRIMARY key (id)
  )
`;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I don't know what to write instead of the concatenated values?

Comment: It's supposed to work as it it, with the variables concatenated to the request (but as I wrote, it should be added with prepared query instead)

Comment: If I write it concatenated, it says id is not defined, so I wrote it like this: `const JoinCreditCard = 'UPDATE users SET creditcard=(SELECT id FROM creditcards) WHERE users.id = creditcards.id';` and now it works but the creditcard column in users is still `NULL` in mySQL.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how will the connection with the id's be? A user with id 5 will be connected with a credit card with id 5? The comparison will not work in my opinion.

Comment: No, you misunderstood some things, the "ready to works as in" version is the first (with `name="' +  name + "` as clause -> you know name at his point). The second version specifies "I assume at this point, you know the id of your user" (which is represented by the concatenated var `id`). The clause you introduced in wrong, the user id is **not the same** as the card id. The connection with the user will be that the `id` in creditcard table will be the same as `creditcard` in users table (you could rename the field `creditcard_id` if you want it to be clear). This is the purpose of this query.

Comment: But I don't want to write the number and the name hard coded, I want it to be automatically connected with the user.

Comment: I don't understand.. nothing is hard coded in the code above, these are concatenated variables, you're not supposed to replace them by fixed values, just use the variables you have..

Comment: What doesn't work when you use the first one with your code in the question (without the suggested recommendations)?

Comment: Unterminated string constant (104:101) - and it shows the: `"`

Comment: You're right, I just forgot a `'`, I edited the answer. (You sould have seen it yourself :D)

Comment: So now when I create a credit card with the same name as a user, the `creditcard` column in users should change?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal of this query

Comment: I try to help you the best I can, but if you don't do a little effort too I can do nothing. "doesn't seem to work" is not an explaination, if there is an error, share the error, if it _seem_ not to work, check if values are correct, if not, share what's unexpected. This is a very simple `UPDATE` query, it it doesn't work, it's probably because the code you shared is not the same than your actual code. Precisions are welcome, how do you execute `JoinCreditCard` query? How is it chained with `createNewCreditCard` query? I can't guess all this.. you can edit the question if needed

Comment: see my **EDIT**. You need to do the query for `JoinCreditCard` with `con.query` or else nothing will happen ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that. Thank you so much for your helpful answer!

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help! Good luck for the rest

Answer (score 0):

it is important that the tables are in normalized forms.
There should be 3 tables.
Users -- all the user data
Credit cards -- all the credit card related information.
Users credit card map -- map users to credit card information.

Comment: Hi, that's the only way of making it work? Can you show me an example of how I can write it?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userscreditcardmap(
   user_id INT(11) NOT NULL ,creditcard_id INT(11) NOT NULL)